# How to generate array with Template Literal Types items

Tags: typescript, type-inference, template-literals

I have UNO card deck that I want to be type safe.
Each card in the deck array is represented by a 2 char string consting of a colour and a value. I am using a `Template Literal Type` for the `CardType`.

```
type SpecialCard = "S" | "R" | "D"; // Skip | Reverse | Draw 2
type NumberCard = number;
type Color = "R" | "Y" | "G" | "B";
type WildCard = "W" | "W4";
type CardType = `${Color}${(NumberCard | SpecialCard)}` | WildCard;
```

Now I'd like to create a set of cards like this:

```
const StandardDeck: CardType[] = (["R", "Y", "G", "B"] as Color[])
  .map<CardType[]>((color) =>
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "S", "R", "D"].map<CardType>(
      (v) => `${color}${v}`
    )
  ).flat()
```

However this gives me an error on this line:

```
(v) => `${color}${v}`
```

```
Type '`R${number}` | `Y${number}` | `G${number}` | `B${number}` | `R${string}` | `Y${string}` | `G${string}` | `B${string}`' is not assignable to type 'CardType'.
  Type '`R${string}`' is not assignable to type 'CardType'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CardType'.
      Type '`R${string}`' is not assignable to type '"BD"'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"BD"'.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGBLAhgGwMLIE4BMoF4oAiGIqAH2ICUzKiARIgbigHpXYBrRMCqKiADcIWAM7RK9LMgDuUAEwAoUJCgA5AK4BbAEYjMuAlAB22vVibLw0dAHtUtrEaI0+RAJq1iAcS9EAQsxWqgDqiKg4BniERCF+IQAsQSo22DgAKtZGAAYAJADedg5YAL4FABSauvppfHAQSGhRAJQl2XxhEVGWivC2xqLAsMDIxjhp9A2cAFxQUZmQANoAukbliy5EADTEnjtEvvuBq8iic-aOK82KUFAAdFrIYAA889YAfOXlfcXNBO83W5QRYABh2AEYdvIdgBmHYJHYAVh2ADYdgB2HYADh2AE59qR9jR9oxlg8nq80gsIJ9AUCoOVBH98O8oHl8j9HGV8oI2nSoNdbs07gAzVDIYDlZpAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 10 September 2022**

You can do even better. You can generate exact literal type of return value:

**Version 2**

```js
type SpecialCard = "S" | "R" | "D"; // Skip | Reverse | Draw 2
type Color = "R" | "Y" | "G" | "B";
type Indexes = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9

type CardName = Indexes | SpecialCard

type Add<Clr extends Color, Name extends CardName[]> = {
    [Index in keyof Name]: `${Clr}${Name[Index]}`
}

type Compute<
    Clrs extends Color[],
    Names extends Array<CardName>,
    Acc extends string[] = []
> =
    (Clrs extends []
        ? Acc
        : (Clrs extends [
            infer Head extends Color,
            ...infer Rest extends Array<Color>
        ]
            ? Compute<Rest, Names, [...Acc, ...Add<Head, Names>]>
            : Acc)
    )

function applyColor<
    TColor extends Color,
    Colors extends TColor[]
>(colors: [...Colors]): <
    ColorKeys extends CardName,
    ColorMap extends ColorKeys[]
>(colorMap: [...ColorMap]) =>
        Compute<Colors, ColorMap>
function applyColor<TColor extends Color, Colors extends TColor[]>(colors: [...Colors]) {
    return <ColorKeys extends CardName, ColorMap extends ColorKeys[]>(colorMap: [...ColorMap]) =>
        colors
            .flatMap((color) =>
                colorMap.map((v): `${Colors[number]}${ColorKeys}` => `${color}${v}`)
            )
}

const makeDeck = applyColor(["R", "Y", "G", "B"])

// exact type representation of runtime value
const StandardDeck = makeDeck([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "S", "R", "D"])

const thirdElement = StandardDeck[2] //R2

console.log({ thirdElement }) // R2
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NngGkm)

`Compute` and `Add` utility types are doing exact same thing as runtime representation but with recursion.

SImilar approach I have used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630242/unable-to-define-type-for-tuple-target-requires-2-elements-but-source-may-hav#answer-73631072)

**Version 1**

---

```js
type SpecialCard = "S" | "R" | "D"; // Skip | Reverse | Draw 2
type NumberCard = number;
type Color = "R" | "Y" | "G" | "B";
type WildCard = "W" | "W4";

type Indexes = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9

type CardType = `${Color}${(NumberCard | SpecialCard)}` | WildCard;


const applyColor = <Colors extends Color[]>(colors: [...Colors]) =>
  <ColorKeys extends Indexes | SpecialCard, ColorMap extends ColorKeys[]>(colorMap: [...ColorMap]) =>
    colors
      .map((color) =>
        colorMap.map((v): `${Colors[number]}${ColorKeys}` => `${color}${v}`)
      ).flat()

const makeDeck = applyColor(["R", "Y", "G", "B"])

// ("R0" | "R4" | "R1" | "R2" | "R3" | "R5" | "R6" | "R7" | "R8" | "R9" | "RR" | "RS" 
// | "RD" | "Y0" | "Y4" | "Y1" | "Y2" | "Y3" | "Y5" | "Y6" | "Y7" | "Y8" | "Y9" | "YR" | "YS" | "YD" | "G0" | ... 24 more ... | "BD")[]
// 28+24 = 52 elements in the union
// exactly same number of elements is in runtime value
const StandardDeck = makeDeck([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "S", "R", "D"])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGBLAhgGwMLIE4BMoF4oAiGIqAH2ICUzKiARIgbigHpXYBrRMCqKiADcIWAM7RK9LMgDuUAEwAoUJCgA5AK4BbAEYjMuAlAB22vVibLw0dAHtUtrEaI0%20RAJq1iAcS9EAQsxWqgDqiKg4BniERCF%20IQAsQcHQAJLGOBAAHhCiRgAMfACMfPJ8AMx8CXwArHwAbHwA7HwAHHwAnIopUFEAKtZGAAYAJADedg5YAL7jABSauvrYeJRwEEhoUQCU00N8YRFRlt2K8LbGosBQyGBgqCCTjkYAPH1PTtnAEBl5HwA0vXsjjyXx%20ODy72BWAA2gBdAB8c3OU1EAC4oDCAHQ4j6iOHbAgIxRQKAvD4AaQgIFBWW%20vyg6UyOTyawQKAwK0BHwAsrcoGCGZTqaJ4UiUY4%20WAMdjcdCpQSiSTSVAJWJlSqoFitLc5sjoYT8MTNZq1VLtbq5oJthjRhNoaLTEssHDZvaplSaXsiVA7Wq3YI9tsNSrtliAGaoZDAObBs4XK5QHWcCD0DacIy3e6PaFzGEuIiAjyFnwlgJEAnddhQOYufJ%20KhJNxUIoN%20QN8oNmoN%20oNpoN1oNjoN1x0KikKCKatjxhudz1udNujuVtz9tzztz7tz3tz-tzwdz4dz0fEdwT5ezujeBeUHFYhTVLSOaD3tz%20RjbeFTjjyVoAankapCBqMoIFQCAtB%20YA8kQYwoGAAALaANGMRALh-AUsmQeBgAeKBRGQKCTDMEQoFscMBQgqDjBgqBEFg%20CsFQ4BEGIwQ0A0CB40ua4YGAZAMhWNN4AzQhk1TdM83yQEikBeRAXKQEEkBGpAXqQEmkBVpAQ6ItSCLGgi0YSsgA)

**Explanation**

I have used `curry` pattern to make it more readable and [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) for inference

As you might have noticed, in order to infer types I have used a function instead of just a value.

If you want to type something complicated, first of all try to infer each function argument. The more strict inference - the better.

Hover your mouse on `applyColor(["R", "Y", "G", "B"])`. You will see that array is infered with each element, not just `string[]`. Same with `makeDeck`.

It is easy to infer a tuple of primitives. You just need to create generic for a tuple `Colors` and apply appropriate constraint `extends Color[]`.

In the second function, apart from infering whole tuple, I also infered a tuple element `ColorKeys`. I did it because I have used it in `(v) =>` ${color}${v}`` for typing the return type.

TypeScript is smart enough to infer exact type of `${color}${v}`.

If you are interested in function argument inference you can read my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments). It is not finished yet but it already has some useful explanation and examples.

P.S. It seems to be that `WildCard` does not exist in a runtime.

P.S.S. [Here](https://catchts.com/string-combinations) you can find my article

Comment: Very, very nice. It seems I need to learn a lot more about TS in the future ;)
Yes, WildCard I omitted for brevity. 
Now the full UNO deck has the rows 0..9SRD and 1..9SRD for each colour + 4xW + 4W4.
Could that also be integrated with a nice trick?

Comment: Do you mean smth like this ? : `[...result, '4xW','4W4'] `

Comment: Not its like one could say in Ruby 4.time("W") + 4.times("W4")

Comment: Plplease provide the runtime value which you want to get. After that, I will provide types

Comment: @philk I'm not familiar with Ruby

Comment: What I was looking for is `new Array(4).fill("W")` and `new Array(4).fill("W4")` to complete the deck of cards. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You better to create separate func for this. Sorry, I'm on vacation now