# Unable to define type for tuple: Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer

Tags: javascript, typescript, tuples

I'm trying to populate an array consisting of tuples

```js
const countries = ['sg', 'my', 'th'];
const platforms = ['ios', 'android'];

const combinationsToQuery = platforms.flatMap((platform) =>
    countries.map((cid) => [platform, cid])
); // [["ios", "sg"], ["ios", "my"], ["ios", "th"], ["android", "sg"], ["android", "my"], ["android", "th"]]
```

Now I'm trying to add some types to them and below is my attempt

```js
type country = 'sg' | 'my' | 'th' | 'uk' | 'us'
type platform = 'ios' | 'android'

const countries: country[] = ['sg', 'my'];
const platforms: platform[] = ['ios', 'android'];

const combinationsToQuery: [platform, country][] = platforms.flatMap((platform) =>
    countries.map((cid: country) => [platform, cid])
);
```

> Type '(country | platform)[][]' is not assignable to type '[platform, country][]'.
> Type '(country | platform)[]' is not assignable to type '[platform, country]'.
> Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.(2322)

If I don't specifically define `[platform, country][]`, TS will infer `combinationsToQuery` to be `(country | platform)[][]`, which doesn't sounds right either?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=9&ssc=75&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAxg9gVwHbAE4igXigcgM4DmOUAPrgLYjFk7AAWOAUKJFGADYCGwAZnKuSy4AlnDzVcnJABNUcYdKaN4SPMFiIUqYRDwAuDcjQgA2gF0hJ-EQA0FKmYDcyuKvUdufAfrZde-cnNLHFFxOxwpWXlFJ0YXNw1yACNhJG5RVQAVOABFBAh0AxMPfwE7eCN0MyDsEq9yPAA6Hj8AWU4wAApOuoCASiwAPkYoUcMtHSbyDu6YBQMKrRABzEGoYr968oUzPsY%20xygAeiP1q1CccMIcMztzsUv7G7uImTkFR%20tn9deoj-DKDczEA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem becomes more obvious if you look at the return type for the `.map` callback. If you tweak your original code to:

```
countries.map((cid: country) => {
  const result = [platform, cid];
  return result;
})
```

Above, `result` is typed as `(country | platform)[]` - *not* as a tuple containing two elements, but as an array whose (any number of) elements are either `platform` or `country`. (So, the resulting type of the whole `combinationsToQuery` isn't right either.)

You can either assert the type returned by the callback is a tuple:

```
const combinationsToQuery: [platform, country][]  = platforms.flatMap((platform) =>
    countries.map((cid) => [platform, cid] as [platform, country])
);
```

Or declare your arrays `as const` and the return value from the callback `as const` and let TypeScript infer the rest for you.

```
const countries = ['sg', 'my'] as const;
const platforms = ['ios', 'android'] as const;

const combinationsToQuery = platforms.flatMap((platform) =>
    countries.map((cid) => [platform, cid] as const)
);
```

Comment: I'm not happy with the assertion required in `as [platform, country]` - but the `as const` approach will occasionally be problematic if the resulting type must be used later without the `readonly`. Don't know how to say that an array literal should be interpreted as a tuple without `as`.

Comment: usually you can use variadic tuple types for type inference of tuples, in this case you almost never need to use `as const` assertion, but from the other hand, your argument needs to be a literal value

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is a convention in TS, that you need to Capitalize all type names, otherwise, it is hard to read.

As for this type:

```js
type country = 'sg' | 'my' | 'th' | 'uk' | 'us'
type platform = 'ios' | 'android'

const countries: country[] = ['sg', 'my'];
const platforms: platform[] = ['ios', 'android'];
```

Using `country[]` type for `countries` const is not safe, because it allows you to use duplicates:

```js
const countries: country[] = ['sg', 'sg']
```

Hence, we need to use smth more useful:

```js
type Country = 'sg' | 'my' | 'th'
type Platform = 'ios' | 'android'

// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-692864087
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S] | R>;
}[U];


type Countries = TupleUnion<Country>
type Platforms = TupleUnion<Platform>

const countries: Countries = ['sg', 'my'];

const platforms: Platforms = ['ios', 'android'];

const should_be_error : Platforms = ['ios', 'ios'] // error
```

As you might have noticed, `Countries` and `Platforms` are combination of all possible/allowed values.

So, now, we have to apply each platform to each country. Or in other words, we need a permutation of these two sets.

COnsider this example:

```js
type Country = 'sg' | 'my' | 'th'
type Platform = 'ios' | 'android'

// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-692864087
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S] | R>;
}[U];


type Countries = TupleUnion<Country>
type Platforms = TupleUnion<Platform>

const countries: Countries = ['sg', 'my'];

const platforms: Platforms = ['ios', 'android'];

type Add<Plat extends string, Cntrs extends string[]> = {
    [Index in keyof Cntrs]: [Plat, Cntrs[Index]]
}

type Compute<
    Plats extends string[],
    Cntrs extends string[],
    Acc extends string[][] = []
> =
    /**
     * If last call of recursion
     */
    (Plats extends []
        /**
         * Return Accumulator
         */
        ? Acc
        /**
         * If this is not the last step, infer first and rest elements
         */
        : (Plats extends [
            infer Head extends string,
            ...infer Rest extends string[]
        ]
            /**
             * Call Compute recursively using Rest as a main tuple (Platforms)
             * and call our Add "callback", which just adds Head element to each Country
             */
            ? Compute<Rest, Cntrs, [...Acc, ...Add<Head, Cntrs>]>
            : Acc)
    )

function combinations<P extends Platforms, C extends Countries>(platforms: P, countries: C): Compute<P, C>
function combinations<P extends Platforms, C extends Countries>(platforms: P, countries: C) {
    return platforms.flatMap((platform) =>
        countries.map((cid) => [platform, cid])
    )
}

// [["ios", "sg"], ["ios", "my"], ["android", "sg"], ["android", "my"]]
const result = combinations(platforms, countries)

console.log({ result })
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXjdQm)

As you might have noticed, `Compute` type utility does the same thing as your runtime code with one difference - it uses recursion instead of regular array iteration.

Also, there is no need to use `as const` assertion

P.S.S. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69265186/how-to-generate-array-with-template-literal-types-items/69265799#69265799) you can find related answer and [here](https://catchts.com/string-combinations) is my article